# delete cookie of an sub domain

Tags: c#, .net, cookies, subdomain

i have a domain for example :  example.com
and i have sub-domain : sub.example.com

the users on the site is sharing the same session & cookies,
but how can i remove cookies from both the domains ?

for now i delete from one domain and when the goes the the sub-domain he is logged in again ..

much thanks. shlomi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete a cookie by setting it's expiration date to a datetime that has already been passed. You can do the same for a subdomain.

```
HttpCookie appCookie = new HttpCookie("AppCookie");
appCookie.Value = "written " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
appCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
appCookie.Path = "/PathToSubDomain";
Response.Cookies.Add(appCookie);
```

To clarify, the path is the path relative to the main domain. You "sub" should be a folder inside the main domain. `sub.example.com` is in fact something like exampleRoot/sub/ so this is the Path you put to your cookie and you set the datetime to an old datetime to remove the cookie from this subdomain.